# Emacs lisp -- how to submit `&&` to shell?

Tags: bash, elisp

I want to string together some shell commands with `&&` -- for instance,

```
wget -c http://repository/file.tar.gz && tar -xzvf file.tar.gz && rm file.tar.gz
```

Normally I would use `start-process`, but this function seems to be confused by the `&&`. I can just run the three commands in sequence, but in this case as in many others, I want to ensure that the first command was not aborted in error before the second command executes, and so on.

Python's `subprocess.call` function has a `shell=True` argument by which you can just send the whole line -- is there such a function in emacs lisp, or in this case I should look for another workaround?

Comment: you can test with simpler commands, `echo 1 && echo 2 && echo 3`. I would try escaping the '&'s like `\&\&`. Good luck.

Comment: I think the problem is that `&&` and `;` are not recognized as arguments to the `process` being called...

Comment: m0skit0: if you are suggesting using `;` instead of `&&` then that's no good, because they are semantically different. When you use `&&` you ensure that each command in the sequence is executed *only* if all of the previous ones succeeded. YMMV, but I know that I only very rarely want `;`, and you most certainly wouldn't want to use `;` in the example from this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `shell-command`.